# Inverse Fast Fourier Transform to find the voltage across a capacitor of a RC circut

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, convolution, signal-processing

## Fourier transform of a RC circuit

---

> The following example of a RC circuit describes the use of the fourier transform in order to receive the output voltage across the capacitor.

My questions are:

- Have I used the convolution correct?
- How can I solve this problem numerically using the inverse fast fourier transform (iFFT) and receive the same result?

---

The wanted result of the convolution is the impulse response for the voltage across the capacitor which is:
$$
v_C\left(t\right)=V_0\left(1-e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}\right)
$$

Input signal $V_{in}\left(\omega\right)$ (rectangular function) and capacitor transfer function $H_c\left(\omega\right)$:
$$\begin{align}
 V_{in}\left(\omega\right)&=V_0\,\tau\;\text{sinc}\left(\frac \tau2 \omega\right)\\
 H_C\left(\omega\right)&=\frac{1}{i\,\omega\,RC+1}
\end{align}$$

Output signal $V_C\left(\omega\right)$ is a convolution of $H_C\left(\omega\right)\cdotp V_{in}\left(\omega\right)$:
$$\begin{align}
 V_C\left(\omega\right)&=H_C\left(\omega\right)\cdotp V_{in}\left(\omega\right)\\
 v_C\left(t\right)&=h_C\left(t\right)* v_{in}\left(t\right)
\end{align}$$

The convolution in time domain with the corresponding functions where $\sigma$ is the Heaviside function leads to the correct answer:
$$\begin{align}
 h_C\left(t\right)&=\frac{1}{RC}\cdot e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}\cdot\sigma\left(t\right)\\
 v_{in}\left(t\right)&=V_0\left(\sigma\left(t+\frac \tau2\right)-\sigma\left(t-\frac \tau2\right)\right)=
\begin{cases}
 V_0, & |t|\le\tau/2 \\
 0,   & \text{every other $t$}
\end{cases}\\
\\
 v_C\left(t\right)&=h\left(t\right)*x\left(t\right)
                   =\int_{-\infty}^\infty h_C\left(t\right)\cdotp v_{in}\left(t-u\right)\,du\\
                  &=\frac{V_0}{RC}\int_{0}^\tau e^{-\frac{u}{RC}}\,du\\\\
 v_C\left(t\right)&=V_0\left(1-e^{-\frac{\tau}{RC}}\right)
\end{align}$$